# SQL: Apply an aggregate result per day using window functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions, window-functions

Consider a time-series table that contains three fields `time` of type *timestamptz*, `balance` of type *numeric*, and `is_spent_column` of type *text*.

The following query generates a valid result for the last day of the given interval.

```
SELECT
    MAX(DATE_TRUNC('DAY', (time))) as last_day,
    SUM(balance)  FILTER ( WHERE is_spent_column is NULL ) AS value_at_last_day
FROM tbl
```

> 2010-07-12    18681.800775017498741407984000

However, I am in need of an equivalent query based on window functions to report the total value of the column named `balance` for all the days up to and including the given date .

Here is what I've tried so far, but without any valid result:

```
SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC('DAY', (time)) AS daily,
    SUM(sum(balance) FILTER ( WHERE is_spent_column is NULL ) ) OVER ( ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('DAY', (time)) ) AS total_value_per_day
FROM tbl
group by 1
order by 1 desc
```

> 2010-07-12   16050.496339044977568391974000
>
> 2010-07-11   13103.159119670350269890284000
>
> 2010-07-10   12594.525752964512456914454000
>
> 2010-07-09   12380.159588711091681327014000
>
> 2010-07-08   12178.119542536668113577014000
>
> 2010-07-07   11995.943973804127033140014000

---

EDIT:

Here is a sample dataset:
LINK REMOVED

The running total can be computed by applying the first query above on the entire dataset up to and including the desired day. For example, for day `2009-01-31`, the result is 97.13522530000000000000, or for day `2009-01-15` when we filter time as `time < '2009-01-16 00:00:00'` it returns `24.446144000000000000`.

What I need is an alternative query that computes the running total for each day in a single query.

EDIT 2:

Thank you all so very much for your participation and support.

The reason for differences in result sets of the queries was on the preceding ETL pipelines. Sorry for my ignorance!

Below I've provided a sample schema to test the queries.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/veUiRauLs23s3WUfXQu3WE/2

Now both queries given above and the query given in the answer below return the same result.

Comment: have you run without  the window function? besides please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @nbk yes, the first query above returns exactly what I need and uses no window functions. But as we know, we have to use window functions to apply aggregation result to all records.

Comment: The first query doesn't do what you think, just to be clear.  That sum is not limited to the last day.  It's a sum over all rows in the table/group that match the filter... and the group just happens to be the entire table because there's no GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @JonArmstrong Yes, I wanna calculate a running total. Suppose we have a table `tbl` with 10 records. If we run the first query 10 times, each run involves a time interval begining from the first day to the last day of the interval, we get the desired output.

Comment: Have you tested the SQL?  It should do exactly what you asked, assuming the groups represent your intervals and you order the window function over the grouped results properly.  If you don't like the result, add your test case to the question and ask a more specific question, including what you don't like in your result.

Comment: Please explain *without any valid result*. What is wrong with that result? Since we do not have your data, only you can tell us! Actually, remove the outer `SUM` and `GROUP BY`. Running totals should return same rows as non-aggregated data.

Comment: Your csv file is not sufficient. Where is the date component of the time column?  It looks like 2 rows (out of 2587) have a date component, but that seems accidental... and the balance never changes.

Comment: You would probably never want to sum the balances (even if they were correct), but instead sum the change in balance (delta).   Please post the corrected data and then explain clearly what the data represents (each value of each row) and then explain what you wish to calculate.  Calculating a running total when you already have the balance doesn't seem right, unless you want some running delta from start to the current period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider calculating running total via window function *after* aggregating data to day level. And since you aggregate with a single condition, `FILTER` condition can be converted to basic `WHERE`:

```sql
SELECT daily,
       SUM(total_balance) OVER (ORDER BY daily) AS total_value_per_day
FROM (
    SELECT
        DATE_TRUNC('DAY', (time)) AS daily,
        SUM(balance) AS total_balance
    FROM tbl
    WHERE is_spent_column IS NULL
    GROUP BY 1
) AS daily_agg
ORDER BY daily
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The result set of your query is exactly the same as my second query. Let me add sample data and a minimal reproducible query to my question.

Comment: @sci9 That's because they are logically identical... and do just what you seem to have asked... except for the tiny difference in `FILTER` behavior.

Comment: @JonArmstrong and Parfait Please see my edits. I hope I clarified what I'm asking about.

Comment: Please explain why this query returns undesired results which you do not yet clarify. How does it not *compute the running total for each day in a single query*? Also, your data appears to only contain date information for first two values of column.

Comment: @JonArmstrong and Parfait  Thank you for your valuable comments. The strange results were due to the differences in data generators before the current pipeline. Please see my edits.